# Hive Error: compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 15:0 missing EOF at 'collection' near ''\n''

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-query

I'm new to hive and I'm creating a table with the following properties,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EXTTBL_Transactions
(
    TRANSACTION_ID varchar(70) COMMENT 'UniqueID, `Primary Key',
    DEFINITION_ID varchar(70) COMMENT 'Definition, Null Allowed',
    USER_ID varchar(70) COMMENT 'Contact id, Foreign Key',
    PURCHASE_DATETIME Timestamp COMMENT 'Saved dattime, Null Allowed',
    PURCHASE_AMOUNT FLOAT COMMENT 'Sum  value of number of product purchase,Null Allowed',
    INTERACTIONS_ID varchar(70) COMMENT 'Unique interaction id, Foreign Key',
    PRODUCT_DETAILS array<struct<PRODUCT_NAME:varchar(70),PRODUCT_PRICE:FLOAT>> COMMENT 'Product Details'
)
COMMENT 'Transaction details'
PARTITIONED BY (LOAD_DATE DATE)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
collection items terminated by '|'
map keys terminated by ':'
LOCATION 's3a://XXX/XXX//Transactions';
```

In the code above I'm creating an array of struct type for the product details.   And I'm separating each product details with '|' and struct element by ':', but somehow this is causing an error.

Comment: Wow, that was so quick. Thanks for link.

Comment: Let me know if that works, I don't typically have such text formats in my Hive tables

Comment: After sequencing query,It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to answer.

The order should be `FIELDS`, `COLLECTION ITEMS`, `MAP KEYS`, and then `LINES`

[Hive DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable)

```
row_format
  : DELIMITED [FIELDS TERMINATED BY char [ESCAPED BY char]] [COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY char]
        [MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY char] [LINES TERMINATED BY char]
```